# Yii - Attaching a behavior in CActiveDataProvider

Tags: php, yii, behavior

I am looking for a way how to attach a behavior to model displayed in a grid view in Yii Framework. The grid view is using CActiveDataProvider and I need every $data element to have a behavior attached to it. The model shouldn't attach the behavior after construct, since it is related to the grid view only.

Thanks

Comment: What type of behavior are you trying to attach?

Answer (score 1):

You can create the following class to use to create a data provider.

```
ActiveDataProvider extends CActiveDataProvider{

  public function getData(){
    $data = parent::getData();

    foreach($data as &$model){
       $model->attachBehavior('aName', new mybehavior());
    }
    return $data;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option (instead of creating a CActiveDataProvider override as suggested in another answer) is to do all your model querying ahead of time and attach your behaviors in your controller. Then pass to a CArrayDataProvider.

Hmm, thinking about it, I like the other approach better :-) I'll leave this for completeness sake.